# Errors while building MVC 6 source code from https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build MVC 6 source code from github.I've installed dnvm and pulled source code from repo as decriped in https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/wiki/Building-MVC then i run build using cmd (as administrator). But I've errors when building like (there're 50 errors):

```
C:\Dev\Sandbox\ASP.NET5\mvc\src\Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch\project.json(0,0): error NU1002: The dependency System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.0 in project Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
C:\Dev\Sandbox\ASP.NET5\mvc\src\Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch\project.json(0,0): error NU1002: The dependency System.Globalization.Calendars 4.0.0 in project Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
C:\Dev\Sandbox\ASP.NET5\mvc\src\Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch\project.json(0,0): error NU1002: The dependency System.ObjectModel 4.0.10 in project Microsoft.AspNet.JsonPatch does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
```

.... errors go on...

The build set deafult dnvm as  1.0.0-rc1-15838 clr x86 - does it matter?
When opening solution in VS 2015 Community I've got errors next to References - DNX 5.0 Core as on [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5gpQ.png)

Can anyone give me any clue?

Comment: I have to stress that I'm trying to build latest mvc6 framework source code (branch master) from github.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, if you install dnvm/dnx you just have stable channel runtime (beta8) while the packages already want to compile against rc1 (unstable ATM).

Just download the unstable runtime

```
dnvm install -r coreclr -arch x64 latest -u
```